# edit the first word on each line of multiple text file in multiple folder using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have multiple text files in multiple folder.
In each text files, it consist of this;

```
0 0.211328 0.386111 0.088281 0.197222
3 0.283984 0.319444 0.067969 0.161111
2 0.387109 0.514583 0.102344 0.112500
```

I would like to edit the first number on each line to 0, which will look like this;

```
0 0.211328 0.386111 0.088281 0.197222
0 0.283984 0.319444 0.067969 0.161111
0 0.387109 0.514583 0.102344 0.112500
```

so far after scouring through stack overflow, i managed to do the code successfully using this script;

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %y IN (1,1,10000) DO IF EXISTS %y.txt (
    (for /F "tokens=1*" %a in (%y.txt) do (
        FOR /F %c IN ("!var:~0,1!") DO echo 0 %b 
        )
    )
) >%y_.txt
```

however this only works if my .txt filename is a number. I set the range to 10000 because I'm processing over thousands of textfiles in 1 folder. And, this code create a new textfile with the name %y_.txt which %y hold the name of the accessed file and I add _ to avoid filename confusion.

I might need the new text file to just replace the old ones with the same name but by using %y as the new filename doesn't work.

hold on, that's not only it.

I also might need to edit all other .txt files which is located in the one upper folder from this one. The tree folder looks pretty much like this;

```
   D:
    ├───Folder-A
    │   ├───folder-1
    │   │   ├──1.txt
    │   │   ├──2.txt
    │   │   └──3.txt
    │   └───folder-2
    │       ├──a.txt
    │       └──b.txt
    │
    └───Folder-B
        ├───folder-x
        │   ├──8.txt
        │   ├──9.txt
        │   └──10.txt
        └───folder-y
            ├──y.txt
            └──z.txt
```

The previous code only works if I am in a specific folder directory and it doesn't go into subfolders.
I tried using `dir /b/s *.txt` but I'm not sure where to put it.

I hope someone could help me out here. By the way, this is my first time using batch script and also my first task as a graduate trainee. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will recursively go through the sub directories and find all `.txt` files and replace the first item with in each line with `0`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.txt') do (
    for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ('type %%~a') do (
     (echo 0 %%j)>>"%%~dpna.tm"
  )
   if exist "%%~dpna.tm" move /Y "%%~dpna.tm" "%%~fa"
 )
```

**Note** before you run this! This will create a temp file with the content of the original, once it made the relevant change, it will rename the file to the original (from temp file) so please do not run this in your prod env, until you have tested it in a dummy `dir` All levels of your dummy directory needs to have temp text files, else this will replace every first whitespace occurring word with a `0`

You might also want to add `pushd "C:\somedir"` after `@echo off` and `popd` at the end of the script to ensure it runs the the directory you want it to run in.

Comment: Thanks this is great. Can you explain a little bit about %~dpna and %~fa? what does it do? and what does the sign represent? because this code will prompt if i want to move and replace the existing file. Can I not deal with the prompt since the prod env would be like A LOT of files. Thank you though :)

Comment: You can see all the variable expansion options by running for /? from `cmd` but `%%~dpna` expands drive, path and name of the file, excluding the extension simply so we can create a new tmp extension where we xan make the changes. `%%~fa` is the entire file path. Just add `/Y` to the end of the move command to stop the command from prompting, Updated answer to demonstrate it.